# Is there a standard nomenclature for model names suffixed by strings such as "Q4_K_S"?

Tags: terminology, models, notation

Many models specify details using prefixes such as `Q6_K` or `Q4_K_S`.

It seems obvious that the `Q` portion refers to quantization; what about the other characters?

Is there a standard nomenclature reference for this?

Comment: Can you please point us to a reference/link/webpage that uses this notation?

Comment: Just about any huggingface model page, such as this one: https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.1-GGUF